# Multiple get API in MEAN.IO (Express, Angular)

Tags: angularjs, rest, express, mean-stack, mean.io

In traditional REST API, we should define our API like this:

- GET     /api/things              ->  get all
- POST    /api/things              ->  create
- GET     /api/things/:id          ->  get one
- PUT     /api/things/:id          ->  update
- DELETE  /api/things/:id          ->  delete

How should i define another **'get one'** endpoint for querying data by any other field other than id? For example:

- GET /api/things/:title -> get one by title    (this sure does not work since the api isn't aware of URL parameter names)
- GET /api/things/title/:title ? this does not work for me at all..
- GET /api/things?title=whatever  (this cannot be defined at all. When i write this in my index.js:

  router.get('?title=whatever', controller.getByTitle);

I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^?title=whatever\/?$/: Nothing to repeat
    at RegExp (native)
```

Comment: Use query parameters? `GET /api/things?title=whatever`. But so long as you document in clearly for the users, you can pick whatever you like.

Comment: I have added this detail to the question

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know what endpoint you want to expose, or that you're incapable of implementing it? The former is opinion-based, but the latter would be on-topic with a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID should be an unique identifier. Given one ID, you should return one resource at most. That's why an URI like `GET /api/things/:id` makes sense.

For other properties which may or may not be unique, you can have more than one result, so use the GET `/api/things` endpoint and pass query parameters : `/api/things?title=mytitle`.

```
app.get('/api/things', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.title); //mytitle
    ThingModel.find({
       title: req.query.title    
    }, function (err, things) {
         res.send(things);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have just realised how stupid the question is :/ sorry. Thanks

Comment: I have just tried this, but my get request does not send the parameters. It looks like this: $http.get('/api/things', {name:'name'}), but the called URL is still "/api/things". Where may i have error

Comment: Wrap your query parameters in a `params` object:

$http.get('/api/things', {
    params: {
        name: 'name'
    }
});

Comment: Thanks. i have also just found out that special case by GET. But in general, should we handle our queries always with this one 'GET api'? For example i now have to query some 'things' based on many criteria, and get them in a different order. Should i never create another GET api, and always use this one GET /things api?

Comment: You should use the same `GET` uri. You can pass in your request more parameters: a text search string, a sort string, a limit...
For example: `/api/things?title=mytitle&sort=title&order=asc&limit=3`, and in your endpoint you would do the sort and limit using `req.query.sort`, `req.query.order`, `req.query.limit`

Comment: and when i want to query using a JSON object instead of string? For example i want to query using this {'age': { '$gt' : 18 } } ?   I have tried to send this with using encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({json}), this will be converted to string and sent to get api, but how will i read this data from req.query at server side?  JSON.parse(req.query) also did not help..

Comment: JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(req.query.param)) at the server side does the job. thank you.